# Facebook handler not get called

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

Starting an activity from main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FacebookActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Defining handler:

```
public class FacebookActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
```

But handler not get called. I see this in console:

```
calling onResume for activity
```

Any idea, what is the problem? In an earlier version I did not used separate activity for facebook login, and there login handler worked. Strange.

Comment: check my suggestion below let me now if you still have the problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**

Initialize facebook SDK before initializing `CallbackManager`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

**Step 2**

Then in onActivityResult() forward the login results to the callbackManager created in onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Work, can u explain why `onActivityResult` needs?

Comment: @János, if you checked Facebook SDK classes then LoginManager's onActivityResult() will be triggered from onActivityResult() of CallbackManager. You can debug code if you want to understand flow.

Answer (score 0):

Call the following code before the `setContentView`

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to Initialize Facebook-Sdk

add these lines before this line

setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager  = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```